# Replace any value matching a specific value in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

I would like to replace a value in any level of nested document where it is equal to a predefined value. How can I achieve that? I am able to loop through all document in the collection and all properties in the document but do not know how to handle nested levels

What I have right now

```
function Replace() {
  var replacement = { oldValue: "abc", newValue: "def" }
  db.MyCollection.find().forEach((it)=> { 
   for (var prop in it) {
      if (it.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        console.log("Property:", prop);
        console.log("Value:", it[prop]);
        // Comparison and replacement 
        // Only hande the first level. How can I handle all nested level?
      }
    }
  })
}
Replace();
```

Comment: You need to use Recursive function to achieve this

Comment: you can write a js function inside $function

Comment: Pumping out the entire collection to the client is very inefficient.

Comment: I am running it directly on NoSql Booster for MongoDb. I though it would be executed on the DB? @AlexanderPetrov

Answer (score 1):

You can write a javascript code snippet and execute it on the `mongosh` itself. Something like this:

```
db = connect('mongodb://localhost/database-name');
const replacement = { oldValue: "abc", newValue: "def" }
const docs = db.collectionName.find({}).toArray();
for (let j = 0; j < docs.length; j++) {
     updateValue(docs[j])
     db[collections[i]].replaceOne({ _id: docs[j]._id }, docs[j]);
}
​
function updateValue(doc) {
    Object.keys(doc).forEach(key => {
        if (doc[key] === replacement.oldValue) {
            doc[key] = replacement.newValue;
        } else if (doc[key] instanceof Object && !Array.isArray(doc[key])) {
            updateValue(doc[key])
        } else if (Array.isArray(doc[key])) {
            doc[key].forEach(val => {
                updateValue(val)
            })
        }
    })
}
```

This snippet will update one document at a time. Please note that since it is based on recursion, the script might fail if you have around too many nested levels.

Comment: Pumping out the entire collection to the client is very inefficient.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov we can process in batches as well. I just wanted to give an outlook on how this can be done.